# Enum element with associated values must have at least one associated value

Tags: swift

This syntax of defining enum with associated values used to work fine with Swift 4.2

```
enum NetworkService {
    case lookUp(type: String)
    case allLookUps()
}
```

When I am trying to convert my code in Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5, it is throwing error saying

> Enum element with associated values must have at least one associated
>   value
>   [image]

It doesn't make any sense in this particular case to have associated value for allLookUps(). So what is the best practice here in Swift 5?

Comment: You wrote *It doesn't make any sense in this particular case to have associated value for allLookUps()*. Now read the suggested fixes. Which one matches your statement?

Comment: Xcode10.2 has some issue. When I try to select the first fix, it only removes one of () brackets and second suggestion makes it look like getLookUpsVoid() lol! Guess getting rid of () seems to work fine. Guess I made a redundant post here :P

Comment: If you don't need associated values then remove it  and just keep `case  allLookUps` , it can't be empty

Comment: Take help from here -> https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11

Comment: Of course Fix #1 is the proper one. *No associated value* means no parentheses.

Comment: Such dumb question. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply remove the brackets () after the case:

```
enum NetworkService {
    case lookUp(type: String)
    case allLookUps
}
```

Comment: that solution is ok, but this warning in Xcode is very sticky and I was unable to fix this warning until I have moved enum declaration into another file.

Comment: @Argus in Xcode 11.3.1, I was able to get rid of the sticky warning by running Product...Clean Build Folder after removing the ().

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the parenthesis in your second case "allLookUps" 
Only include the parenthesis when you want to add an associated value to the Enum case.

source: https://youtu.be/EwHmyAUeG3I